# "Bindear" comando en MenuItem

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Buenas,

He añadido en un MenuItem la propiedad Command pero no funciona

El código del xaml es el siguiente:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Categorias}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategoria, Mode=TwoWay}"
    HasUnevenRows="false"
    RowHeight="55"
    Margin="40,0,25,0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.ContextActions>
            <MenuItem Text="Ver" />
            <MenuItem Text="Eliminar"
                      Command="{Binding EliminarCategoria}" />
            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
          <templates:CategoriaListItemTemplate/>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

El código del ViewModel es el siguiente:

```
public CategoriasViewModel(
ICategoriasService categoriaService,
ISqliteService sqliteService,IUserDialogs  userDialogService)
    {
        _categoriaService = categoriaService;
        _sqliteService = sqliteService;
        _userDialogService = userDialogService;

        EliminarCategoria = new Command(ExecuteEliminarCategoria);


    }

    public Command EliminarCategoria { get; private set; }
    private async void ExecuteEliminarCategoria()
    {
        var categoria = SelectedCategoria;

        var sqlCategoria = new Models.Categorias.SqlCategorias
        {
            idCategoria = categoria.idCategoria,
            name = categoria.name,
            activated = false
        };

        await _sqliteService.Insert(sqlCategoria);


        _userDialogService.Toast("Categoria eliminada del catálogo.");

    }
```

¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Gracias.

Comment: seria bueno tambien ver como tienes tu **.CS** para ver el código que realizaste

Comment: Ya está añadido Miguel Osorio

Answer (score 0):

> El problema es que **el contexto de bindeo (BindingContex)** dentro de tu **ItemTemplate** es, obviamente, **solo tu Item,** asi que acceder al comando **definido en el ViewModel** y no en el objeto en si mismo es un poco mas dificil.

Pero podemos solucionarlo asi:

El código del xaml es el siguiente:

```
<ContentPage ...
    x:Name="CurrentPage">

<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Categorias}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategoria, Mode=TwoWay}"
    HasUnevenRows="false"
    RowHeight="55"
    Margin="40,0,25,0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.ContextActions>
            <MenuItem Text="Ver" />
            <MenuItem Text="Eliminar" Command="{Binding BindingContext.EliminarCategoria,Source={x:Reference CurrentPage}}" />
            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
          <templates:CategoriaListItemTemplate/>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
...
</ContentPage>
```

### Porque usar Source?

Al usar Source solo en el comando, el resto del template sigue teniendo como contexto el Item, que es lo apropiado para un Template.

Suerte, espero te sirva.